How to locate an element using CSS Selector for a calendar component
I am a beginner and have started to learn POM. To that end, I am trying to create an automated test using  chrome Webdriver( gradle prj in IntelliJ) and in particular I am trying to define an object using:
 WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver();
 WebElement obj_name=  driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("css_selector_element");

in my automation framework.
For that, my learning scenario is on booking.com / Flights section and when you open the calendar I am unable to correctly locate the 'next arrow' to go through the months .
Example:
span[class='Icon-module__root___kmTzd Icon-module__root--size-medium___znUOh']

This one has 3 items and on the page, the element that I need is the third , I have tried using css=E *:last-child , however I cannot figure it out.

There is another way to locate this ( which works..'ish) , however the class is frequently changed on booking( it's expected I know that), which is why I am trying to find the element that does not always change. I must admit, I am not quite there  yet with learning, but it is hard to find material with a sense of user friendly without any help from a trainer. Thanks and I really appreciate any help.
I have used this CSS locator:
button[class='Actionable-module__root___qDg24 Button-module__root___UX0nO Button-module__root--variant-tertiary___NzSX6 Button-module__root--icon-only___6AzQz Button-module__root--size-large___nriSY Button-module__root--variant-tertiary-neutral___dovTd Calendar-module__control___naNU5 Calendar-module__control--next___XQFDe']

.. but it is clearly not ok

I was able to locate the missing element using css=E:nth-child(2)
